# Unable to align div content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am developing an application using Vue.js and Bootstrap. I am looking to develop a folder to look like this:

[image]

But, I am unable to align the contents to make sure that it looks like in the above picture.

The picture currently looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
  <stats-card>
    <div slot="header" class="folderRectangle">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <i class="material-icons" id="folder-image">folder</i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <div class="clearfix" style="position: relative">
            <div>
              <p style="text-align: left">Folder Name</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p style="text-align:left">20 files</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </stats-card>
</div>
```

What wrong am I doing? How do I make sure that the folder icon aligns to the top and text floats to the center?

Comment: Are you somehow using both boostrap and vue-material together?

Comment: No. I am not using both together, material-icons is only for icons "<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">"

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `.row` and `.col-*`, you can use the [`media object`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/) already available in Bootstrap to produce this layout.

```css
/* demo only */

.media {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 25px; 
}

.media-body {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/png/20181213/folder-vector-icon-png_267455.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h6 class="mt-0 mb-1">Folder name</h6>
    <div>20 files</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to achieve what you are trying is to use CSS Flex property.

- Just give display flex to the parent (col-9) in your case.
- Provide align items to be center.
- and at last flex alignment to row.

this will make you achieve the above design

You can read about CSS flexbox more here
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp